# How do I enable TimeSpans in Google Sky?

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a google earth application that run's in the sky view, in previous versions of Google Earth I was able to use the TimeSpan element within features (such as placemarks) such that I could animate placemarks as they moved across the sky. It appears that in the latest release of Google Earth this functionality has been disabled in Sky view. If it is possible, how do I re-enable it?